# Как выбрать первый хост с одинаковым значением переменной?

Tags: ansible

В файле hosts есть такая секция:

```
[postgresql]
pg-alpha-01 postgresql_instance=alpha
pg-alpha-02 postgresql_instance=alpha
pg-beta-a   postgresql_instance=beta
pg-beta-b   postgresql_instance=beta
pg-beta-c   postgresql_instance=beta
```

На этих хостах инициализируется master-slave postgresql и при инициализации мне нужно один из хостов группы (у которых одинаковый `postgresql_instance`) выбрать в качестве мастера. И так как неважно какой это будет хост, то пусть будет просто первым из списка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала думал просто задать вопрос, но посчитал неуважительным сначала не потрудиться самостоятельно. И в итоге всё получилось.

Плейбук:

```
---
  - hosts: postgresql
    gather_facts: no
    tasks:
    - name: Search first host
      set_fact:
        f_init_master_host: "{{ v_init_master_host }}"
        f_init_master_host_is_current_host: "{{ v_init_master_host == inventory_hostname }}"
      vars:
        v_init_master_host: "{{ groups['postgresql'] | map('extract', hostvars) | selectattr('postgresql_instance', 'equalto', postgresql_instance) | map(attribute='inventory_hostname') | list | first }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "First host for {{ inventory_hostname }}: {{ f_init_master_host }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "Current host is master: {{ f_init_master_host_is_current_host }}"
```

Результат:

```
TASK [debug] ************
ok: [pg-alpha-01] => 
  msg: 'First host for pg-alpha-01: pg-alpha-01'
ok: [pg-alpha-02] => 
  msg: 'First host for pg-alpha-02: pg-alpha-01'
ok: [pg-beta-a] => 
  msg: 'First host for pg-beta-a: pg-beta-a'
ok: [pg-beta-b] => 
  msg: 'First host for pg-beta-b: pg-beta-a'
ok: [pg-beta-c] => 
  msg: 'First host for pg-beta-c: pg-beta-a'

TASK [debug] ************
ok: [pg-alpha-01] => 
  msg: 'Current host is master: True'
ok: [pg-alpha-02] => 
  msg: 'Current host is master: False'
ok: [pg-beta-a] => 
  msg: 'Current host is master: True'
ok: [pg-beta-b] => 
  msg: 'Current host is master: False'
ok: [pg-beta-c] => 
  msg: 'Current host is master: False'
```